# How to change array index position in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Actually i used this code in my live site

```
    <?php $path = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];    
    $pathParts = explode('/', $path);
    if (count($pathParts) == 3) {
        echo $currParentCategory = strtolower($pathParts[2]);
    }
    elseif(isset($pathParts[3]) && strtolower($pathParts[3]) == "customize-furnitures") {
        $currParentCategory = strtolower($pathParts[3]);
    }
    if(!$currParentCategory)
    {
        $path = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
        $pathParts = explode('/', $path);
        if (count($pathParts) == 3) {
            $currParentCategory = strtolower($pathParts[2]);
        }
        elseif(isset($pathParts[3]) && strtolower($pathParts[3]) == "customize-furnitures") {
            $currParentCategory = strtolower($pathParts[3]);
        }
    } ?>

    <?php if($currParentCategory == "customize-furnitures"): ?>
<?php echo "Customize product" ;?>
<?php else: ?>
        <?php echo "Simple product"  ?>
```

This is my live site url `https://domain.com/customize-furnitures/test-sofa.html`

The problem is now i configured in my local system now the url is

localhost:8080/Magento/index.php/customize-furnitures/test-sofa.html

so url is changed that's why array index not working how i fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the following?

```
<?php 
    $path = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; 
    if(stristr($path,'customize-furnitures')){
        echo "Customize product" ;
    }else{
        echo "Simple product";
    }
?>
```

**EDIT:**

If the 'customize-furnitures' is not in the request path, it's of course no use to check for it.

You can try the following instead:

```
$currentCatIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$categoryCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('url')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $currentCatIds)
                     ->addIsActiveFilter();
$customizable = false;
foreach($categoryCollection as $cat){
  if($cat->getUrlKey() == 'customize-furnitures'){
       $customizable = true;
  }
}

if($customizable){
   //echo here
}else{
   //echo something else
}
```

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: i am using new product(http://localhost:8080/Magento/index.php/vivid-cane-wicker-chair.html), feature produt and best seller product link like that

Comment: Please see my updated answer, that one should work no matter what the url is.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway i customized my code tha's work fine

Comment: Ok great :-) Good to hear it works